# Full control on screen savers under Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver, control-panel

Under Ubuntu 9.10, I have some screen savers that I like, but I cannot change any option that would otherwise be specific for each screen saver, like for the photo/slideshow, to specify the actual pictures directory. Is there a package I can install that will give me more control, such as what I could for Compiz that gives me all possible options ?

Currently I see some screen savers that talk about furhter options, but there is no button to access such options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean howto create a xml file for a slideshow as wallpaper-changer? see here http://ubuntubond.blogspot.com/2009/12/natgeowall.html

or use wally.
If you mean screensaver there's the option to set a folder of your choise with pics.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the default gnome-screensaver with xscreensaver.

This [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=198809) explains how to do it, but it's quite old. You should probably refer to this [FAQ](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html) too. If you get it working, maybe consider posting an updated guide to the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community)?